# What are some alternatives to 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge' for resolving duplicate Django migrations?

Tags: django, database, migration

I have duplicated migrations that are not applied yet. It causes conflicts and the website cannot be deployed as a result.

I have tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations --merge` but it didn't work. Also, I tried to just delete the migrations, but wasn't able to because of the conflicts. `django-migration-fixer` didn't help either.

I'd like to avoid deleting the database itself. Perhaps, there's another way to solve the issue?

Current migrations state: [showmigrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMVx9.png)